# OrientDB to Android ports

Tags: android, orientdb

Does anyone know the status of OrientDB to Android ports?  I am aware of the wu-man port but it is of OrientDB 1.x.

Thanks in Advance,'
Tony

Comment: As I know it's the only one available at the moment.